# Create a zip file from a generator in Python?

Tags: python, zip

I've got a large amount of data (a couple gigs) I need to write to a zip file in Python.  I can't load it all into memory at once to pass to the .writestr method of ZipFile, and I really don't want to feed it all out to disk using temporary files and then read it back.

Is there a way to feed a generator or a file-like object to the ZipFile library?  Or is there some reason this capability doesn't seem to be supported?

By zip file, I mean zip file.  As supported in the Python zipfile package.

Comment: I did say that, both in the title and the first sentence.  I've added a clarification, although I'm mystified as to why it was needed.  If I just needed any generic compression algorithm, I would have said that in the first place.

Comment: It appears that ZIP means GZIP to most of the world.  So, when you mean ZIP (as in PKWare ZIP), you have to clarify the distinction.  Yes, it's mystifying why people thing GZip when you meant PKWare Zip.

Comment: I guess, winzip, pkware zip and 7zip which are most known zipper(?) applizations' "gzip support" might have driven people to think that gzip implementation might be painless.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only solution is to rewrite the method it uses for zipping files to read from a buffer.  It would be trivial to add this to the standard libraries; I'm kind of amazed it hasn't been done yet.  I gather there's a lot of agreement the entire interface needs to be overhauled, and that seems to be blocking any incremental improvements.

```
import zipfile, zlib, binascii, struct
class BufferedZipFile(zipfile.ZipFile):
    def writebuffered(self, zipinfo, buffer):
        zinfo = zipinfo

        zinfo.file_size = file_size = 0
        zinfo.flag_bits = 0x00
        zinfo.header_offset = self.fp.tell()

        self._writecheck(zinfo)
        self._didModify = True

        zinfo.CRC = CRC = 0
        zinfo.compress_size = compress_size = 0
        self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader())
        if zinfo.compress_type == zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED:
            cmpr = zlib.compressobj(zlib.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, zlib.DEFLATED, -15)
        else:
            cmpr = None

        while True:
            buf = buffer.read(1024 * 8)
            if not buf:
                break

            file_size = file_size + len(buf)
            CRC = binascii.crc32(buf, CRC) & 0xffffffff
            if cmpr:
                buf = cmpr.compress(buf)
                compress_size = compress_size + len(buf)

            self.fp.write(buf)

        if cmpr:
            buf = cmpr.flush()
            compress_size = compress_size + len(buf)
            self.fp.write(buf)
            zinfo.compress_size = compress_size
        else:
            zinfo.compress_size = file_size

        zinfo.CRC = CRC
        zinfo.file_size = file_size

        position = self.fp.tell()
        self.fp.seek(zinfo.header_offset + 14, 0)
        self.fp.write(struct.pack("<LLL", zinfo.CRC, zinfo.compress_size, zinfo.file_size))
        self.fp.seek(position, 0)
        self.filelist.append(zinfo)
        self.NameToInfo[zinfo.filename] = zinfo
```

Comment: Yes, the rewrite is a bummer.  Thank goodness for open source.

Comment: See my answer that takes this approach one step further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297345/create-a-zip-file-from-a-generator-in-python/2734156#2734156

Comment: There is a bug in the provided code; the `fmt` argument to `struck.pack` should be `"<LLL"`, and the line that has `CRC = binascii.crc32(buf, CRC)` should be `CRC = binascii.crc32(buf, CRC) & 0xffffffff`. I'm saying this based on the `zipfile.py` module contents on Python 2.7. What lead me to this is that I was running into `struct.error` exceptions.

Also, it would make sense to use `zlib`.

Comment: You can convert any iterator (including a generator) into a stream (the type of the ```buffer``` 3rd arg) using the recipe at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6658949/108518.

Comment: For some reason I had trouble making this work with Python 2.7.9, I didn't dig to deep into why since it works as expected with 2.7.10 and 2.7.8.

Comment: See my answer below for a solution which does not require self.fp to be seekable

Comment: In case you have those problems writing to sys.stdout[.buffer]: ZipFile thinks that sys.stdout supports seek() and tell() while it really does not, so some tell()-based size computations create negative values leading to the error you describe. Can be solved by wrapping sys.stdout in file-like object with own implementation of tell().

Answer (score 12):

Changed in **Python 3.5** (from official docs): Added [support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) for writing to **unseekable** streams.

This means that now for `zipfile.ZipFile` we can use streams which do not store the entire file in memory. Such streams [do not support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io#io.IOBase.seekable) movement over the entire data volume.

So this is simple generator:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo

def zipfile_generator(path, stream):
    with ZipFile(stream, mode='w') as zf:
        z_info = ZipInfo.from_file(path)
        with open(path, 'rb') as entry, zf.open(z_info, mode='w') as dest:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: entry.read(16384), b''):
                dest.write(chunk)
                # Yield chunk of the zip file stream in bytes.
                yield stream.get()
    # ZipFile was closed.
    yield stream.get()
```

`path` is a string path of the large file or directory or `pathlike` object.

`stream` is the **unseekable** stream instance of the class like this (designed according to [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io)):

```
from io import RawIOBase

class UnseekableStream(RawIOBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self._buffer = b''

    def writable(self):
        return True

    def write(self, b):
        if self.closed:
            raise ValueError('Stream was closed!')
        self._buffer += b
        return len(b)

    def get(self):
        chunk = self._buffer
        self._buffer = b''
        return chunk
```

You can try this code online: https://repl.it/@IvanErgunov/zipfilegenerator

---

There is also another way to create a generator without `ZipInfo` and manually reading and dividing your large file. You can pass the `queue.Queue()` object to your `UnseekableStream()` object and write to this queue in another thread. Then in current thread you can simply read chunks from this queue in iterable way. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue-objects)

**P.S.** 
[Python Zipstream by allanlei](https://github.com/allanlei/python-zipstream) is outdated and unreliable way. It was an attempt to add support for unseekable streams before it was done officially.

Comment: This is actually python3.6+ solution, as ZipFile.open can only open for reading in 3.5.

Comment: I tried running the code - by default it stores the files without compressing them. The problem is, even after enabling compression it still stores files without actual compression. Here's the code that I used (basically just added `compression=ZIP_DEFLATED`): https://gist.github.com/egor83/4c818d002f5f12c8740d83271eca51a4 
Any advice on how to enable compression?

Comment: @egor83 Hi, you should pass compression to `ZipFile(..., compression=...)` and to the `zip_info.compression_type = ...` Example is here: https://replit.com/@IvanErgunov/zipfilegeneratorcompressed#main.py

Comment: @egor83 [python doc with addition options is here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.compress_type)

Answer (score 9):

I took [Chris B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297345/create-a-zip-file-from-a-generator-in-python/299830#299830) and created a complete solution. Here it is in case anyone else is interested:

```
import os
import threading
from zipfile import *
import zlib, binascii, struct

class ZipEntryWriter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, zf, zinfo, fileobj):
        self.zf = zf
        self.zinfo = zinfo
        self.fileobj = fileobj

        zinfo.file_size = 0
        zinfo.flag_bits = 0x00
        zinfo.header_offset = zf.fp.tell()

        zf._writecheck(zinfo)
        zf._didModify = True

        zinfo.CRC = 0
        zinfo.compress_size = compress_size = 0
        zf.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader())

        super(ZipEntryWriter, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        zinfo = self.zinfo
        zf = self.zf
        file_size = 0
        CRC = 0

        if zinfo.compress_type == ZIP_DEFLATED:
            cmpr = zlib.compressobj(zlib.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, zlib.DEFLATED, -15)
        else:
            cmpr = None
        while True:
            buf = self.fileobj.read(1024 * 8)
            if not buf:
                self.fileobj.close()
                break

            file_size = file_size + len(buf)
            CRC = binascii.crc32(buf, CRC)
            if cmpr:
                buf = cmpr.compress(buf)
                compress_size = compress_size + len(buf)

            zf.fp.write(buf)

        if cmpr:
            buf = cmpr.flush()
            compress_size = compress_size + len(buf)
            zf.fp.write(buf)
            zinfo.compress_size = compress_size
        else:
            zinfo.compress_size = file_size

        zinfo.CRC = CRC
        zinfo.file_size = file_size

        position = zf.fp.tell()
        zf.fp.seek(zinfo.header_offset + 14, 0)
        zf.fp.write(struct.pack("<lLL", zinfo.CRC, zinfo.compress_size, zinfo.file_size))
        zf.fp.seek(position, 0)
        zf.filelist.append(zinfo)
        zf.NameToInfo[zinfo.filename] = zinfo

class EnhZipFile(ZipFile, object):

    def _current_writer(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'cur_writer') and self.cur_writer or None

    def assert_no_current_writer(self):
        cur_writer = self._current_writer()
        if cur_writer and cur_writer.isAlive():
            raise ValueError('An entry is already started for name: %s' % cur_write.zinfo.filename)

    def write(self, filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None):
        self.assert_no_current_writer()
        super(EnhZipFile, self).write(filename, arcname, compress_type)

    def writestr(self, zinfo_or_arcname, bytes):
        self.assert_no_current_writer()
        super(EnhZipFile, self).writestr(zinfo_or_arcname, bytes)

    def close(self):
        self.finish_entry()
        super(EnhZipFile, self).close()

    def start_entry(self, zipinfo):
        """
        Start writing a new entry with the specified ZipInfo and return a
        file like object. Any data written to the file like object is
        read by a background thread and written directly to the zip file.
        Make sure to close the returned file object, before closing the
        zipfile, or the close() would end up hanging indefinitely.

        Only one entry can be open at any time. If multiple entries need to
        be written, make sure to call finish_entry() before calling any of
        these methods:
        - start_entry
        - write
        - writestr
        It is not necessary to explicitly call finish_entry() before closing
        zipfile.

        Example:
            zf = EnhZipFile('tmp.zip', 'w')
            w = zf.start_entry(ZipInfo('t.txt'))
            w.write("some text")
            w.close()
            zf.close()
        """
        self.assert_no_current_writer()
        r, w = os.pipe()
        self.cur_writer = ZipEntryWriter(self, zipinfo, os.fdopen(r, 'r'))
        self.cur_writer.start()
        return os.fdopen(w, 'w')

    def finish_entry(self, timeout=None):
        """
        Ensure that the ZipEntry that is currently being written is finished.
        Joins on any background thread to exit. It is safe to call this method
        multiple times.
        """
        cur_writer = self._current_writer()
        if not cur_writer or not cur_writer.isAlive():
            return
        cur_writer.join(timeout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    zf = EnhZipFile('c:/tmp/t.zip', 'w')
    import time
    w = zf.start_entry(ZipInfo('t.txt', time.localtime()[:6]))
    w.write("Line1\n")
    w.write("Line2\n")
    w.close()
    zf.finish_entry()
    w = zf.start_entry(ZipInfo('p.txt', time.localtime()[:6]))
    w.write("Some text\n")
    w.close()
    zf.close()
```

Comment: how about a non-threaded version? threads in Python won't add performance if that's what you intended.

Comment: This is nice but when I try to use it like BytesIO (for creating XML documents with XMLGenerator) I get an exception when I try and close the file. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "bufzip.py", line 62, in run
    zf.fp.write(struct.pack("<LLL", zinfo.CRC, zinfo.compress_size, zinfo.file_size))
error: integer out of range for 'L' format code`

Comment: As Erik noted above there is a typo in the format string must be `"<LLL"` and CRC needs to be `CRC = binascii.crc32(buf, CRC) & 0xffffffff`

Comment: Other than exposing the write stream the rest of the code was from Python built-in classes, so perhaps the bug exists there also?

Answer (score 3):

gzip.GzipFile writes the data in gzipped chunks , which you can set the size of your chunks according to the numbers of lines read from the files.

an example:

```
file = gzip.GzipFile('blah.gz', 'wb')
sourcefile = open('source', 'rb')
chunks = []
for line in sourcefile:
  chunks.append(line)
  if len(chunks) >= X: 
      file.write("".join(chunks))
      file.flush()
      chunks = []
```

Comment: For obscure reasons the result must be a ZIP file, not a GZIP file or any other compressions.  [The comments was insulting, so I deleted them.]

Comment: Unspecified is not the same as obscure.  The archive files I produce need to be opened by office workers in a Windows environment.  They all have zip utilities.  None have GZIP.

Answer (score 3):

The essential compression is done by zlib.compressobj.  ZipFile (under Python 2.5 on MacOSX appears to be compiled).  The Python 2.3 version is as follows.

You can see that it builds the compressed file in 8k chunks.  Taking out the source file information is complex because a lot of source file attributes (like uncompressed size) is recorded in the zip file header.

```
def write(self, filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None):
    """Put the bytes from filename into the archive under the name
    arcname."""

    st = os.stat(filename)
    mtime = time.localtime(st.st_mtime)
    date_time = mtime[0:6]
    # Create ZipInfo instance to store file information
    if arcname is None:
        zinfo = ZipInfo(filename, date_time)
    else:
        zinfo = ZipInfo(arcname, date_time)
    zinfo.external_attr = st[0] << 16L      # Unix attributes
    if compress_type is None:
        zinfo.compress_type = self.compression
    else:
        zinfo.compress_type = compress_type
    self._writecheck(zinfo)
    fp = open(filename, "rb")

    zinfo.flag_bits = 0x00
    zinfo.header_offset = self.fp.tell()    # Start of header bytes
    # Must overwrite CRC and sizes with correct data later
    zinfo.CRC = CRC = 0
    zinfo.compress_size = compress_size = 0
    zinfo.file_size = file_size = 0
    self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader())
    zinfo.file_offset = self.fp.tell()      # Start of file bytes
    if zinfo.compress_type == ZIP_DEFLATED:
        cmpr = zlib.compressobj(zlib.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
             zlib.DEFLATED, -15)
    else:
        cmpr = None
    while 1:
        buf = fp.read(1024 * 8)
        if not buf:
            break
        file_size = file_size + len(buf)
        CRC = binascii.crc32(buf, CRC)
        if cmpr:
            buf = cmpr.compress(buf)
            compress_size = compress_size + len(buf)
        self.fp.write(buf)
    fp.close()
    if cmpr:
        buf = cmpr.flush()
        compress_size = compress_size + len(buf)
        self.fp.write(buf)
        zinfo.compress_size = compress_size
    else:
        zinfo.compress_size = file_size
    zinfo.CRC = CRC
    zinfo.file_size = file_size
    # Seek backwards and write CRC and file sizes
    position = self.fp.tell()       # Preserve current position in file
    self.fp.seek(zinfo.header_offset + 14, 0)
    self.fp.write(struct.pack("<lLL", zinfo.CRC, zinfo.compress_size,
          zinfo.file_size))
    self.fp.seek(position, 0)
    self.filelist.append(zinfo)
    self.NameToInfo[zinfo.filename] = zinfo
```

Comment: Yes, after I posted the question I looked at the source code.  You're right that it uses the file info for the heading, but there's no need for it to do that--in fact, it overwrites some of the information afterwards anyway.  I've posted a rewrite of the method which does what I need.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the rewrite, since it relies on the internals of the Python library to work, but there really doesn't seem to be any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Some (many? most?) compression algorithms are based on looking at redundancies across the *entire*  file.

Some compression libraries will choose between several compression algorithms based on which works best on the file.

I believe the ZipFile module does this, so it wants to see the entire file, not just pieces at a time.

Hence, it won't work with generators or files to big to load in memory. That would explain the limitation of the Zipfile library.

Comment: +1 agreed. Its not impossible (see Chris B.s answer), but I think it may make more sense to give the compression algorithm the whole thing. The analysis, needed to generate a good huffman coding tree, is then more accurate and with respect to the whole file. Therefore the result could be much smaller/better-compressed.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, which is still relevant in 2017 for Python 2.7, here's a working solution for a true streaming zip file, with no requirement for the output to be seekable as in the other cases. The secret is to set bit 3 of the general purpose bit flag (see https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT section 4.3.9.1).

Note that this implementation will always create a ZIP64-style file, allowing the streaming to work for arbitrarily large files. It includes an ugly hack to force the zip64 end of central directory record, so be aware it will cause all zipfiles written by your process to become ZIP64-style.

```
import io
import zipfile
import zlib
import binascii
import struct

class ByteStreamer(io.BytesIO):
    '''
    Variant on BytesIO which lets you write and consume data while
    keeping track of the total filesize written. When data is consumed
    it is removed from memory, keeping the memory requirements low.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super(ByteStreamer, self).__init__()
        self._tellall = 0

    def tell(self):
        return self._tellall

    def write(self, b):
        orig_size = super(ByteStreamer, self).tell()
        super(ByteStreamer, self).write(b)
        new_size = super(ByteStreamer, self).tell()
        self._tellall += (new_size - orig_size)

    def consume(self):
        bytes = self.getvalue()
        self.seek(0)
        self.truncate(0)
        return bytes

class BufferedZipFileWriter(zipfile.ZipFile):
    '''
    ZipFile writer with true streaming (input and output).
    Created zip files are always ZIP64-style because it is the only safe way to stream
    potentially large zip files without knowing the full size ahead of time.

    Example usage:
    >>> def stream():
    >>>     bzfw = BufferedZip64FileWriter()
    >>>     for arc_path, buffer in inputs:  # buffer is a file-like object which supports read(size)
    >>>         for chunk in bzfw.streambuffer(arc_path, buffer):
    >>>             yield chunk
    >>>     yield bzfw.close()
    '''
    def __init__(self, compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED):
        self._buffer = ByteStreamer()
        super(BufferedZipFileWriter, self).__init__(self._buffer, mode='w', compression=compression, allowZip64=True)

    def streambuffer(self, zinfo_or_arcname, buffer, chunksize=2**16):
        if not isinstance(zinfo_or_arcname, zipfile.ZipInfo):
            zinfo = zipfile.ZipInfo(filename=zinfo_or_arcname,
                                    date_time=time.localtime(time.time())[:6])
            zinfo.compress_type = self.compression
            zinfo.external_attr = 0o600 << 16     # ?rw-------
        else:
            zinfo = zinfo_or_arcname

        zinfo.file_size = file_size = 0
        zinfo.flag_bits = 0x08  # Streaming mode: crc and size come after the data
        zinfo.header_offset = self.fp.tell()

        self._writecheck(zinfo)
        self._didModify = True

        zinfo.CRC = CRC = 0
        zinfo.compress_size = compress_size = 0
        self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader())
        if zinfo.compress_type == zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED:
            cmpr = zlib.compressobj(zlib.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, zlib.DEFLATED, -15)
        else:
            cmpr = None

        while True:
            buf = buffer.read(chunksize)
            if not buf:
                break

            file_size += len(buf)
            CRC = binascii.crc32(buf, CRC) & 0xffffffff
            if cmpr:
                buf = cmpr.compress(buf)
                compress_size += len(buf)

            self.fp.write(buf)
            compressed_bytes = self._buffer.consume()
            if compressed_bytes:
                yield compressed_bytes

        if cmpr:
            buf = cmpr.flush()
            compress_size += len(buf)
            self.fp.write(buf)
            zinfo.compress_size = compress_size
            compressed_bytes = self._buffer.consume()
            if compressed_bytes:
                yield compressed_bytes
        else:
            zinfo.compress_size = file_size

        zinfo.CRC = CRC
        zinfo.file_size = file_size

        # Write CRC and file sizes after the file data
        # Always write as zip64 -- only safe way to stream what might become a large zipfile
        fmt = '<LQQ'
        self.fp.write(struct.pack(fmt, zinfo.CRC, zinfo.compress_size, zinfo.file_size))

        self.fp.flush()
        self.filelist.append(zinfo)
        self.NameToInfo[zinfo.filename] = zinfo
        yield self._buffer.consume()

    # The close method needs to be patched to force writing a ZIP64 file
    # We'll hack ZIP_FILECOUNT_LIMIT to do the forcing
    def close(self):
        tmp = zipfile.ZIP_FILECOUNT_LIMIT
        zipfile.ZIP_FILECOUNT_LIMIT = 0
        super(BufferedZipFileWriter, self).close()
        zipfile.ZIP_FILECOUNT_LIMIT = tmp
        return self._buffer.consume()
```

Comment: Nice work, this worked for me without a hitch. I tested on a 65MB file and a 270MB file and my memory profiler showed less than 1 MB of incremental memory regardless of input file size. The zip file size was the same as it was when I compared with a zip file created with std tools, and it opened without complaint on OSX and Win.

Comment: Two minor typos to fix: add ```import time``` and in example usage, should be ```BufferedZipFileWriter``` instead of ```BufferedZip64FileWriter```

Comment: I am new to python, but here how did you guys created a buffer?

Answer (score 0):

The gzip library will take a file-like object for compression.

```
class GzipFile([filename [,mode [,compresslevel [,fileobj]]]])
```

You still need to provide a nominal filename for inclusion in the zip file, but you can pass your data-source to the fileobj.

*(This answer differs from that of Damnsweet, in that the focus should be on the data-source being incrementally read, not the compressed file being incrementally written.)*

*And I see now the original questioner won't accept Gzip :-(*

Answer (score 0):

Now with python 2.7 you can add data to the zipfile insted of the file :

http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr

Answer (score 0):

This is 2017. If you are still looking to do this elegantly, use [Python Zipstream by allanlei](https://github.com/allanlei/python-zipstream). 
So far, it is probably the only well written library to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

gzip.GzipFile writes the data in gzipped chunks , which you can set the size of your chunks according to the numbers of lines read from the files.

an example:

```
file = gzip.GzipFile('blah.gz', 'wb')
sourcefile = open('source', 'rb')
chunks = []
for line in sourcefile:
  chunks.append(line)
  if len(chunks) >= X: 
      file.write("".join(chunks))
      file.flush()
      chunks = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stream-zip](https://github.com/uktrade/stream-zip) for this (full disclosure: written mostly by me).

Say you have generators of bytes you want to zip:

```py
def file_data_1():
    yield b'Some bytes a'
    yield b'Some bytes b'

def file_data_2():
    yield b'Some bytes c'
    yield b'Some bytes d'
```

You can created a single iterable of the zipped bytes of these generators:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from stream_zip import ZIP_64, stream_zip

def zip_member_files():
    modified_at = datetime.now()
    perms = 0o600
    yield 'my-file-1.txt', modified_at, perms, ZIP_64, file_data_1()
    yield 'my-file-2.txt', modified_at, perms, ZIP_64, file_data_2()

zipped_chunks = stream_zip(zip_member_files()):
```

And then, for example, save this iterable to disk by:

```py
with open('my.zip', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in zipped_chunks:
        f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [zipstream-ng](https://github.com/pR0Ps/zipstream-ng) library handles this exact scenario:

```py
from zipstream import ZipStream

def my_iterator():
    yield b"some bytes"

def my_other_iterator():
    yield b"some bytes"

zs = ZipStream()
zs.add(my_iterator(), "file.ext")
zs.add(my_other_iterator(), "otherfile.ext")

with open("out.zip", "wb") as fp:
    fp.writelines(zs)
```