# How to convert an iterable to a stream?

Tags: python, stream, iterator

If I've got an iterable containing strings, is there a simple way to turn it into a stream? I want to do something like this:

```
def make_file():
    yield "hello\n"
    yield "world\n"

output = tarfile.TarFile(…)
stream = iterable_to_stream(make_file())
output.addfile(…, stream)
```

Comment: I don't know streams well, but do you want `stream = io.StringIO("".join(make_file()))` ?

Comment: Nope — I don't want that. `make_file()` may return a large file, and I'd rather not load it into memory.

Comment: interesting link: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab162f925761/Lib/tarfile.py#l249

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Sorry, I don't think I see the significance of that link…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my streaming iterator an experimental branch of [urllib3](http://code.google.com/p/urllib3/) supporting streaming chunked request via iterables:

```
class IterStreamer(object):
    """
    File-like streaming iterator.
    """
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.generator = generator
        self.iterator = iter(generator)
        self.leftover = ''

    def __len__(self):
        return self.generator.__len__()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterator

    def next(self):
        return self.iterator.next()

    def read(self, size):
        data = self.leftover
        count = len(self.leftover)

        if count < size:
            try:
                while count < size:
                    chunk = self.next()
                    data += chunk
                    count += len(chunk)
            except StopIteration:
                pass

        self.leftover = data[size:]

        return data[:size]
```

Source with context:
https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/filepost-stream/urllib3/filepost.py#L23

Related unit tests:
https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/filepost-stream/test/test_filepost.py#L9

Alas this code hasn't made it into the stable branch yet as sizeless chunked requests are poorly supported, but it should be a good foundation for what you're trying to do. See the source link for examples showing how it can be used.

Comment: This has a bug where it will continue to emit the last leftover bit of data forever.

Comment: Swap out the `pass` for `return data` and the bug is gone.

Comment: No. Swap out the `pass` for `self.leftover = ''; return data` and the bug is gone.

Comment: Fixed the bug you guys mentioned. Sorry for the lack of response, didn't notice Stackoverflow's notifications for a long time. :)

Comment: Hyperlinks are broken.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Thanks for letting me know. Alas I no longer have a mirror of that branch. :( Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Good news. Found a backup. Updated the links. :)

Comment: Your `__iter__` implementation is incorrect as it should iterate over the lines, not the chunks of the iterator.

Comment: `read` still has a bug with stale leftover, fixed by the changes in this diff https://github.com/jennyyuejin/Kaggle/commit/cf1d1cb3a23ae8b4d0a04ace457205822287e3c4#diff-ab728ad73e7b49ee43631f0875573409R26

Comment: Thank you James -- your version seems to be the only one that completely fixes the stale leftover.

Funny how difficult this has proven to be.

Answer (score 50):

Python 3 has [a new I/O stream API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/) ([library docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/io.html)), replacing the old file-like object protocol. (The new API is also available in Python 2 in the [`io`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html) module, and it's backwards-compatible with the file-like object protocol.)

[Here's an implementation for the new API](https://gist.github.com/mechanical-snail/7688353), in Python 2 and 3:

```
import io

def iterable_to_stream(iterable, buffer_size=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    """
    Lets you use an iterable (e.g. a generator) that yields bytestrings as a read-only
    input stream.

    The stream implements Python 3's newer I/O API (available in Python 2's io module).
    For efficiency, the stream is buffered.
    """
    class IterStream(io.RawIOBase):
        def __init__(self):
            self.leftover = None
        def readable(self):
            return True
        def readinto(self, b):
            try:
                l = len(b)  # We're supposed to return at most this much
                chunk = self.leftover or next(iterable)
                output, self.leftover = chunk[:l], chunk[l:]
                b[:len(output)] = output
                return len(output)
            except StopIteration:
                return 0    # indicate EOF
    return io.BufferedReader(IterStream(), buffer_size=buffer_size)
```

Example usage:

```
with iterable_to_stream(str(x**2).encode('utf8') for x in range(11)) as s:
    print(s.read())
```

Comment: In 2020 and with Python 3.8, is still the best way to do it? Tried it and it still works, but maybe it can be simplified?

Answer (score 12):

Since it doesn't look like there is a "standard" way of doing it, I've banged together a simple implementation:

```
class iter_to_stream(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.buffered = ""
        self.iter = iter(iterable)

    def read(self, size):
        result = ""
        while size > 0:
            data = self.buffered or next(self.iter, None)
            self.buffered = ""
            if data is None:
                break
            size -= len(data)
            if size < 0:
                data, self.buffered = data[:size], data[size:]
            result += data
        return result
```

Answer (score 3):

A starting point:

```
class iterable_to_stream:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iter = iter(iterable)

    def read(self):
        try:
            return self.iter.next()
        except StopIteration:
            return ""
```

Comment: Hhmm… While that would most certainly explode on its own (what if `next(iter)` returns `""`? What if someone has the audacity to pass a size into `read(…)`)… I guess I could use a `BufferedReader` to take care of those details…

Comment: Sorry dude, this appears to be unworkable. BufferedReader needs an instance of `RawIOBase`, and this doesn't come anywhere near to implementing that interface… And it doesn't even implement the basic stream API (eg, `read()` doesn't accept a size).

Comment: @David Wolever: Seems like coding a `RawIOBase`-like wrapper for your iterable and passing that to `BufferReader` would be feasible. `RawIOBase` objects only have 4 methods and you might be able to get away with only implementing the 3 `read...()` ones.

Answer (score 1):

A bit modified version of a great [Mechanical snail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20260030/1185394)'s answer. Here, `readinto(b)` implementation makes multiple calls to the the underlying iterator, in order to gather as much as possible amount of bytes for the size of the given writable bytes-like object `b`.

```py
class IteratorReader(io.RawIOBase):

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator
        self.leftover = []

    def readinto(self, buffer: bytearray) -> Optional[int]:
        size = len(buffer)
        while len(self.leftover) < size:
            try:
                self.leftover.extend(next(self.iterator))
            except StopIteration:
                break

        if len(self.leftover) == 0:
            return 0

        output, self.leftover = self.leftover[:size], self.leftover[size:]
        buffer[:len(output)] = output
        return len(output)

    def readable(self) -> bool:
        return True
```

and usage:

```
def iterator1():
    for i in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'):
        res = i * 3
        yield res.encode("utf8")


iterreader = IteratorReader(iterator1())
while True:
    r = iterreader.read(4)
    if not r:
        break
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

TarFile takes anything that provides a [file-like interface](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes) -- so you could either use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) ([`io.StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/io.html) if you are using Python 3.X) to yield what you need to `TarFile.addfile()` or you could create your own class that provides a [file-like interface](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes) and yields what you need.

Comment: Right — but is there any way to stream an iterator through a StringIO? I'd rather not load the entire input file into memory before writing it to the StringIO.

Comment: @David -- not that I know of.  I'd give you an example of wrapping a class around `StringIO`, but it looks like you've got what you need already :-)