# Downloading and zipping files from amazon

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm currently storing all my photos on amazon s3 and using django for my website. I want a to have a button that allows users to click it and have all their photos zipped and returned to them.

I'm currently using boto to interface with amazon and found that I can go through the entire bucket list / use get_key to look for specific files and download them

After this I would need temporarily store them, then zip and return.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908258/generating-file-to-download-with-django)

Comment: close except I still need to download all the images first then deal with the zipping / returning

Comment: are your images located in one folder in s3? or are they located in many folders? also does it have to be django? i would like to use shell scripting

Comment: yes the button allows users to download their own photos. Also the photos are all in hte same bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files) or at this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/151/) to download the file

```
# This is not a full working example, just a starting point
# for downloading images in different formats.

import subprocess
import Image

def image_as_png_pdf(request):
  output_format = request.GET.get('format')
  im = Image.open(path_to_image) # any Image object should work
  if output_format == 'png':
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/png')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.png' % filename
    im.save(response, 'png') # will call response.write()
  else:
    # Temporary disk space, server process needs write access
    tmp_path = '/tmp/'
    # Full path to ImageMagick convert binary
    convert_bin = '/usr/bin/convert' 
    im.save(tmp_path+filename+'.png', 'png')
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf' % filename
    ret = subprocess.Popen([ convert_bin, 
                            "%s%s.png"%(tmp_path,filename), "pdf:-" ],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    response.write(ret.stdout.read())
  return response
```

to create a zip follow the [link that i gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908258/generating-file-to-download-with-django), you can also use zipimport as shown [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django10_zipimport.html) examples are on the bottom of the page, follow the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html) for newer versions

you might also be interested in [this](https://github.com/scanner/django-downloads) although it was made for django 1.2, it might not work on  1.3

Answer (score 1):

Using [python-zipstream](https://github.com/allanlei/python-zipstream/) as patched with [this pull request](https://github.com/allanlei/python-zipstream/pull/2) you can do something like this:

```
import boto
import io
import zipstream
import sys


def iterable_to_stream(iterable, buffer_size=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    """
    Lets you use an iterable (e.g. a generator) that yields bytestrings as a
    read-only input stream.

    The stream implements Python 3's newer I/O API (available in Python 2's io
    module).  For efficiency, the stream is buffered.

    From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20260030/729491
    """
    class IterStream(io.RawIOBase):
        def __init__(self):
            self.leftover = None

        def readable(self):
            return True

        def readinto(self, b):
            try:
                l = len(b)  # We're supposed to return at most this much
                chunk = self.leftover or next(iterable)
                output, self.leftover = chunk[:l], chunk[l:]
                b[:len(output)] = output
                return len(output)
            except StopIteration:
                return 0    # indicate EOF
    return io.BufferedReader(IterStream(), buffer_size=buffer_size)


def iterate_key():
    b = boto.connect_s3().get_bucket('lastage')
    key = b.get_key('README.markdown')
    for b in key:
        yield b

with open('/tmp/foo.zip', 'w') as f:
    z = zipstream.ZipFile(mode='w')
    z.write(iterable_to_stream(iterate_key()), arcname='foo1')
    z.write(iterable_to_stream(iterate_key()), arcname='foo2')
    z.write(iterable_to_stream(iterate_key()), arcname='foo3')
    for chunk in z:
        print "CHUNK", len(chunk)
        f.write(chunk)
```

Basically we iterate over the key contents using boto, convert this iterator to a stream using the `iterable_to_stream` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20260030/729491) and then have `python-zipstream` create a zip file on-the-fly.