AWS Lambda: How to unzip large ZIP file on S3 and upload files back to S3
I have a large zip file provided by a 3rd party (so I can't use a different compression method or anything like that) which is deposited into an S3 bucket on a regular basis.  The file can be reasonably big (2Gb) with something like 50k files in it.  The files within the zip file are XML files which are in the 70k to 100k range in size.
When that file comes in I need to unzip it and place the files into a different location of the same bucket.
I'm trying to write a lambda function in Python to do that.
I've written solutions which work on small files, but they all time out after 15 minutes on big files.
My latest attempt at a streaming solution used the stream-unzip library as a layer.  By my crude calculations it processes roughly 1 file every 2.7 seconds.  That's not even with writing them back to S3.  At that rate it would take something like a day and half to process 50k files.
Here's a synopsis of the code.  I depended on this comment to get even this far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67716044
import json
...
from stream_unzip import stream_unzip
...

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def zipped_chunks(in_bucket_name, in_filepath, in_region='us-gov-west-1'):
    yield from boto3.client('s3', region_name=in_region).get_object(
        Bucket=in_bucket_name,
        Key=in_filepath
    )['Body'].iter_chunks(102400)

def lambda_handler(event, context):

...
    try:
        cur_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(cur_datetime + ":  BEGIN")
        filenum = 0
        for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks(my_bucket_name, zip_filepath)):
            filenum = filenum + 1
            chunk_num = 0
            for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
                chunk_num = chunk_num + 1
                #print(chunk)
                
            if filenum % 1000 == 0:
                cur_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                print(cur_datetime + ":  File number " + str(filenum) + ":  " + str(file_name) + " # of chunks:  " + str(chunk_num))
                
        cur_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(cur_datetime + ":  END")
        
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = "Error extracting ZIP file:  " + str(type(e)) + ":  " + str(e)
        print(error_prefix + error_message)
        

Just to illustrate what I mean, here are the logs from a run I did with that code:
2024-09-13T16:31:20.085Z
INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.11.v7 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws-us-gov:lambda:us-gov-west-1::runtime:d67b56f062769b7151cf7b87f96b6114c15520d33a6e6964d49d508181d135c5
2024-09-13T16:31:20.755Z
START RequestId: 3529bf8c-306d-4bf0-a83e-e1a6b8cf9230 Version: $LATEST
2024-09-13T16:31:20.851Z
BUCKET: idemia-tx-dl-dev-processing
2024-09-13T16:31:20.851Z
FILEPATH: extract/2024-09-09/DL/001/TTXDPS_IDEMIA_CPSMAIL_20240909_001.zip
2024-09-13T16:31:20.851Z
2024-09-13 16:31:20: BEGIN
2024-09-13T16:37:19.388Z
2024-09-13 16:37:19: File number 1000: b'03033123_867447766148600.xml' # of chunks: 2
2024-09-13T16:43:18.203Z
2024-09-13 16:43:18: File number 2000: b'05983127_233907390302466.xml' # of chunks: 3

It timed out after 15 minutes.
Is there a faster way to do this, or should I abandon lambda?  Am I doing something dumb in my code?
Help me, StackOverflow, you're my only hope!  :-)
Seriously, all help is appreciated.  I'm new to AWS so I'm kinda stumped.

Maybe you can use AWS ECS to run your job as a task triggered by a cron (eventbridge scheduler) ? You can have more compute resources and no timeout

ECS Fargate might be a good middle ground.  Served by instances you don't control like Lambda, but allows much longer runtimes (6 hours iirc).

"Is there a faster way to do this" python is not fast.  You'll get much better performance from rust, java, or go, the latter of which also has great concurrency support.  For that matter, the unzip program is probably many times faster than python and you should be able to stream the input into it.

If unzipping takes more than 15 minutes, then AWS Lambda is not the appropriate compute platform to use. However, take a look at smart-open · PyPI, which can write to S3 using normal Python read/write functions. This means you can avoid the additional step of copying the result to S3. For zip handling, see How to read/write zip files. smart-open should be useful for whatever compute you select.

These are all really good suggestions.  As an experiment I undid the streaming aspect and simply unzipped to /tmp and it took a little over a minute.  Going through the resulting files and uploading them to S3 separately still caused a timeout.  According to my calculations 50k files would have taken something like 30 minutes to upload.  I have no idea why streaming was so slow.  I would have thought it would be much faster.

Hello, @DR-Idemia We have similar requirement but not with the files, the processing was taking longer than expected. So we used AWS SQS and ECS tasks to process it. The Flow is like: When there is new file in S3 (On specific path) then a notification will be added in AWS SQS, which will be fetched by ECS tasks and processed one at a time. May you can use similar scenario which will be sutiable in your case.

I neglected to mention that I overcame the 30 minute upload time by parallelizing the uploads.  I uploaded the files in batches in separate threads.  I also thought about doing this in a map step in a step function.  That brought total processing time down to something like 5 minutes, which was acceptable.
