# How to gunzip an iterator?

Tags: python, gzip

I have an iterator producing data, which I want to decompress.

```
import gzip

h = open('myfile.gz', 'rb')
data = iter(lambda: h.read(1024), b'')
gzip.decompress(data)
```

And I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 531, in decompress
    with GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(data)) as f:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'callable_iterator'
```

How can I decompress the iterator? The data can not be loaded into memory.

Comment: Have you tried gzip.open instead?

Comment: If the file is too large this iterator wouldn't help much. You should use "gzip.open" and read the file in blocks of appropriate size.

Comment: @alxrcs the input is the iterator. The provided code is just an example. In my application, I have the iterator, as provided. I do not have the file.

Comment: @MichaelButscher the file is not there in my application. The input I have for decompressing is the iterator.

Comment: Use "next(data)" to get the whole compressed file data at once from the iterator.

Comment: @MichaelButscher the underlying data is 1PB big, and can not be read into memory.

Comment: If you can't modify the iterator there is no chance as it reads the whole file at once.

Comment: @MichaelButscher modified code to show a better fit for my actual data

Comment: I can't believe that it isn't possible to decompress a stream of data that is accessed linearly without seeking, because `gzip -d -c -` in Linux does exactly that - and with appropriate chunking, the output could be presented as an iterator. The only question is whether there is a convenient way to do it in pure python.

Comment: @alaniwi - the public API in the `gzip` module is based around file objects with read/write methods. That's why a generic iterator with some arbitrary block size doesn't work. But your observation is a good one. You could fire up a thread that runs `gzip` as a subprocess and pumps the iterated blocks into stdin, allowing a different thread to pull the decompressed data out.

Comment: `gzip` uses `zlib` - you could use `zlib` directly.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks, `zlib` does the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tdelaney for pointing me in the right direction:

```
import zlib

def unzip_iterable(data):
  decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(wbits=zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)  # gzip format
  for chunk in data:
    yield decompressor.decompress(chunk)

h = open('myfile.gz', 'rb')
data = iter(lambda: h.read(1024), b'')

for chunk in unzip_iterable(data):
    print(len(chunk))
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I decompress the iterator?

You don't. `gzip.decompress()` doesn't work on an arbitrary iterator. You will need to convert the iterator to a byte stream that can be consumed by `gzip.decompress()`. I would start by looking at `BytesIO`.

Comment: In my question I stated "how to decompress an iterator", not "a file". I have provided an example of the iterator I have, but I have no control on how this iterator is instantiated. The file does not exist in my application.

Comment: @blueFast Thanks for the comment. I edited my question with a suggestion.

Comment: That sounds like a plan.

Comment: This other answer might help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593576/adapt-an-iterator-to-behave-like-a-file-like-object-in-python

Comment: @blueFast Another posibility is to do `bytes(data)`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes. I'm not sure this will work, but it would be really quick to try.