# How To Create a Python file-like Object from an Iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, boto3

I am testing the throughput of writing to `S3` from a python `glue` shell job by using the [`upload_fileobj`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj) function from the `boto3` client.  The input to this function is

> Fileobj (a file-like object) -- A file-like object to upload. At a
> minimum, it must implement the read method, and must return bytes.

In order to have the test isolate just the throughput, as opposed to memory or CPU capabilities, I think the best way to use upload_file_object would be to pass an `iterator` that produces `N` bytes of the value `0`.

**In python, how can a "file like object" be created from an iterator?**

I'm looking for something of the form

```
from itertools import repeat

number_of_bytes = 1024 * 1024

zero_iterator = repeat(b'0', number_of_bytes)

file_like_object = something(zero_iterator) # fill in 'something'
```

Which would then be passed to boto3 for writing

```
session.client('s3').upload_fileobj(file_like_object, Bucket='my_bucket')
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: did you consider using `/dev/null` or `/dev/urandom` as a source?

Comment: @Marat I need the test to work in windows, linux, & glue shell jobs.  therefore I cannot assume the same system resources exist universally.  Also, my question is broadly concerned with converting an iterator to a file object.

Comment: well, one way is to subclass `io.BytesIO`, replacing `.read` method with your generator. It just seems much more elegant to use system-provided /dev/null if it was available

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593576/adapt-an-iterator-to-behave-like-a-file-like-object-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simplified version of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70547492/1319998, since we only need to deal with `bytes`, and so should be suitable for boto3's `upload_fileobj`

```py
def to_file_like_obj(iterable):
    chunk = b''
    offset = 0
    it = iter(iterable)

    def up_to_iter(size):
        nonlocal chunk, offset

        while size:
            if offset == len(chunk):
                try:
                    chunk = next(it)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                else:
                    offset = 0
            to_yield = min(size, len(chunk) - offset)
            offset = offset + to_yield
            size -= to_yield
            yield chunk[offset - to_yield:offset]

    class FileLikeObj:
        def read(self, size=-1):
            return b''.join(up_to_iter(float('inf') if size is None or size < 0 else size))

    return FileLikeObj()
```

If you have an iterable that yields bytes, `my_iterable` say, this can be used with boto3 as follows:

```py
target_obj = boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket('my-target-bucket').Object('my/target/key')
target_obj.upload_fileobj(to_file_like_obj(my_iterable)))
```