# read list of strings as file, python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, stringio

I have a list of strings, and would like to pass this to an api that accepts only a `file`-like object, without having to concatenate/flatten the list to use the likes of `StringIO`.

The strings are utf-8, don't necessarily end in newlines, and if naively concatenated could be used directly in `StringIO`.

Preferred solution would be within the standard library (python3.8) (Given the shape of the data is naturally similar to a file (~identical to `readlines()` obviously), and memory access pattern would be efficient, I have a feeling I'm just failing to DuckDuckGo correctly) - but if that doesn't exist any "streaming" (no data concatenation) solution would suffice.

---

[Update, based on @JonSG's links]

Both `RawIOBase` and `TextIOBase` look provide an api that decouples arbitrarily sized "chunks"/fragments (in my case: strings in a list) from a `file-like` read which can specify its own read chunk size, while streaming the data itself (memory cost increases by only some window at any given time [dependent of course on behavior of your source & sink])

`RawIOBase.readinto` looks especially promising because it provides the buffer returned to client reads directly, allowing much simpler code - but this appears to come at the cost of one full copy (into that buffer).

`TextIOBase.read()`  has its own cost for its operation solving the same subproblem, which is concatenating `k` (`k` much smaller than `N`) chunks together.

I'll investigate both of these.

Comment: Why the preference not to use StringIO?

Comment: @JonSG - `StringIO` is fine - but as I understand the docs, there is no provision to use anything but a single string under the hood: what i can't do is concatenate the list of strings, which is large.  Even using the size (which i don't have prior knowledge of, but probably wouldn't increase the big-O of the following) and something like a `MutableString`, the memory size doubles and an extra traversal of the (full, large) string is required.  If there is some way to couple something similar to ~`itertools.chain` with `StringIO`, that would be fine, too.

Comment: Ah, i see. Check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593576/adapt-an-iterator-to-behave-like-a-file-like-object-in-python and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657820/how-to-convert-an-iterable-to-a-stream/20260030#20260030

Comment: @somebitsflipped Can you add a link to 'What is exactly a file-like object in Python' --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359495/what-is-exactly-a-file-li(ke-object-in-python, so that guys like me could try to follow your question/answer (seems interesting to me)

Comment: is this relevant to the problem : Reworking StringIO concatenation in Python (https://lwn.net/Articles/816415/) ?

Comment: @pippo1980 - fair question.  See the official [glosary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) `file object` """An object exposing a file-oriented API (with methods such as read() or write()) to an underlying resource [...] also called _file-like objects_ or _streams_""".  example of `Duck typing`  There are some nuances depending on exact use.  Also, the link you sent has some similarities to this problem, but its focused on making it easier to avoid the `x = "foo" ; x += "bar"` anti-pattern.

Comment: @JonSG - [1-of-2] excellent references, thank you.  From your first link, [JLR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12593675/309433) shows a ~naive `itertools.chain` style approach; the comments back up my fears there about the perf implications of the resulting char-by-char iteration.  [MJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12604375/309433) with `TextIOBase` however seems highly relevant.

Comment: @JonSG [2-of-2] and in your second link, [MS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20260030/309433) using `RawIOBase.readinto` looks to be the same concept as [MJ's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12604375/309433) `TextIOBase` but using an api with a lot less friction for my use. I will have to use & benchmark these two.