# How to load a dataframe from a file containing unwanted characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm in need of some knowledge on how to fix an error I have made while collecting data. The collected data has the following structure:

```
["Author", "Message"]
["littleblackcat", " There's a lot of redditors here that live in the area maybe/hopefully someone saw something. "]
["Kruse", "In other words, it's basically creating a mini tornado."]
```

I normally wouldn't have added `"["` or `"]"` to .txt file when writing the data to it, line per line. However, the mistake was made and thus when loading the file it will separate it the following way:

[image: Pandas Data]

Is there a way to load the data properly to pandas?

Comment: My apologies for the formatting Bentaye, thank you for the edit!

Comment: Can you share your existing code which gives you your dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

On the snippet that I can cut and paste from the question (which I named `test.txt`), I could successfully read a dataframe via

1. Purging square brackets (with `sed` on a Linux command line, but this can be done e.g. with a text editor, or in python if need be)

   ```
   sed -i 's/^\[//g' test.txt # remove left square brackets assuming they are at the beginning of the line
   sed -i 's/\]$//g' test.txt # remove right square brackets assuming they are at the end of the line
   ```
2. Loading the dataframe (in a python console)

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   pd.read_csv("test.txt", skipinitialspace = True, quotechar='"')
   ```

(not sure that this will work for the entirety of your file though).

Comment: Thank you for your response Davide, I'll give this a try and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below code which reads the text in `myfile.text` which looks like below:

```
["Author", "Message"]
["littleblackcat", " There's a lot of redditors here that live in the area maybe/hopefully someone saw something. "]
["Kruse", "In other words ,it's basically creating a mini tornado."]
```

The code below removes `[` and `]` from the `text` and then splits every string in the list of string by `,` excluding the first string which are headers. Some `Message` contains `,`, which causes another column (`NAN` otherwise) and hence the code takes them into one string, which intended. 
Code:

```
 with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    text = my_file.read()
    text = text.replace("[", "")
    text = text.replace("]", "")

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Author': [i.split(',')[0] for i in text.split('\n')[1:]],
    'Message': [''.join(i.split(',')[1:]) for i in text.split('\n')[1:]]
}).applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))
```

Output:

```
    Author                             Message
0   littleblackcat    There's a lot of redditors here that live in the area  maybe/hopefully someone saw something. 
1   Kruse             In other words it's basically creating a mini tornado.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Harv, I have considered this option however my .txt file contains between 3-6 million lines. Hence it is not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

A pure pandas option is to change the separator from `,` to `", "` in order to have only 2 columns, and then, strip the unwanted characters, which to my understanding are `[`,`]`, `"` and space:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
string = '''
["Author", "Message"]
["littleblackcat", " There's a lot of redditors here that live in the area maybe/hopefully someone saw something. "]
["Kruse", "In other words, it's basically creating a mini tornado."]
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(string),sep='\", \"', engine='python').apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('[\"] '))
# the \" instead of simply " is to make sure python does not interpret is as an end of string character
df.columns = [df.columns[0][2:],df.columns[1][:-2]]

print(df)
# Output (note the space before the There's is also gone
#            Author                                            Message
# 0  littleblackcat  There's a lot of redditors here that live in t...
# 1           Kruse  In other words, it's basically creating a mini...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few more options to add to the mix:

1. You could use parse the lines yourself using `ast.literal_eval`, and then load them into a `pd.DataFrame` directly using an iterator over the lines:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import ast
   with open('data', 'r') as f:
       lines = (ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f)
       header = next(lines)
       df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=header)
       print(df)
   ```

   Note, however, that calling `ast.literal_eval` once for each line may not be very fast, especially if your data file has a lot of lines. However, if the data file is not too big, this may be an acceptable, simple solution.
2. Another option is to wrap an arbitrary iterator (which yields `bytes`) in an `IterStream`. This very general tool ([thanks to Mechanical snail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20260030/190597)) allows you to manipulate the contents of any file and then re-package it into a file-like object. Thus, you can fix the contents of the file, and yet still pass it to any function which expects a file-like object, such as `pd.read_csv`. (Note: I've answered a similar question using the same tool, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46310030/190597).)

   ```
   import io
   import pandas as pd

   def iterstream(iterable, buffer_size=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
       """
       http://stackoverflow.com/a/20260030/190597 (Mechanical snail)
       Lets you use an iterable (e.g. a generator) that yields bytestrings as a
       read-only input stream.

       The stream implements Python 3's newer I/O API (available in Python 2's io
       module).

       For efficiency, the stream is buffered.
       """
       class IterStream(io.RawIOBase):
           def __init__(self):
               self.leftover = None
           def readable(self):
               return True
           def readinto(self, b):
               try:
                   l = len(b)  # We're supposed to return at most this much
                   chunk = self.leftover or next(iterable)
                   output, self.leftover = chunk[:l], chunk[l:]
                   b[:len(output)] = output
                   return len(output)
               except StopIteration:
                   return 0    # indicate EOF
       return io.BufferedReader(IterStream(), buffer_size=buffer_size)

   def clean(f):
       for line in f:
           yield line.strip()[1:-1]+b'\n'

   with open('data', 'rb') as f:
       # https://stackoverflow.com/a/50334183/190597 (Davide Fiocco)
       df = pd.read_csv(iterstream(clean(f)), skipinitialspace=True, quotechar='"')
       print(df)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Unutbu!

Answer (score -1):

For now the following solution was found:

```
sep = '[|"|]'
```

Using a multi-character separator allowed for the brackets to be stored in different columns in a pandas dataframe, which were then dropped. This avoids having to strip the words line for line.

Comment: pandas has some string methods implemented for Series objects. Thus, words can be stripped one whole column at a time with the apply method