# How to pre-process data before pandas.read_csv()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a slightly broken CSV file that I want to pre-process before reading it with pandas.read_csv(), i.e. do some search/replace on it.

I tried to open the file and and do the pre-processing in a generator, that I then hand over to read_csv():

```
    def in_stream():
    with open("some.csv") as csvfile:
        for line in csvfile:
            l = re.sub(r'","',r',',line)
            yield l

    df = pd.read_csv(in_stream())
```

Sadly, this just throws a

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'generator'>
```

Although, when looking at Panda's source, I'd expect it to be able to work on iterators, thus generators.

I only found this [article] ([Using a custom object in pandas.read_csv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310030/using-a-custom-object-in-pandas-read-csv)), outlining how to wrap a generator into a file-like object, but it seems to only work on files in byte-mode.

So in the end I'm looking for a pattern to build a pipeline that opens a file, reads it line-by-line, allows pre-processing and then feeds it into e.g. pandas.read_csv().

Comment: Have you tried... `df = pd.DataFrame(in_stream())` ?

Comment: I think you need a `return l`  at end of the in_stream().

Comment: @JonClements I think the constructor doesn't work on iterators.

Comment: @JonClements This does consume the input from the generator, but doesn't parse the fields like read_csv() would.

Answer (score 5):

After further investigation of Pandas' source, it became apparent, that it doesn't simply require an iterable, but also wants it to be a file, expressed by having a read method (is_file_like() in inference.py).

So, I built a generator the old way

```
class InFile(object):
def __init__(self, infile):
    self.infile = open(infile)

def __next__(self):
    return self.next()

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.__next__()

def next(self):
    try:
        line: str = self.infile.readline()
        line = re.sub(r'","',r',',line) # do some fixing
        return line
    except:
        self.infile.close()
        raise StopIteration
```

This works in pandas.read_csv():

```
df = pd.read_csv(InFile("some.csv"))
```

To me this looks super complicated and I wonder if there is any better (→ more elegant) solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that will work for smaller CSV files. All lines are first read into memory, processed, and concatenated. This will probably perform badly for larger files.

```
import re
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

with open('file.csv') as file:
    lines = [re.sub(r'","', r',', line) for line in file]

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(lines)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Alas, I'm looking for an approach that works on huge files, too. The idea is being able to build a complete processing pipeline, streaming data from a source through several processors to its final destination.