# Panda Python error: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I can not change my string to float value. Im new at Python and could not find any similar issues on stack overflow. Sorry if I have missed it...

*Snippet of my data.*

[image]

*My code looks like this*

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

dt = data.rename(columns = {"Unnamed: 0": "test", "Unnamed: 1": "name", "Unnamed: 2": "week"})

dt.dtypes
```

*Output*

```
test           object
name           object
week           object
Total          object
§83            object
§83.1          object
Unnamed: 6     object
Unnamed: 7     object
Unnamed: 8     object
Unnamed: 9     object
Unnamed: 10    object
§83.2          object
Unnamed: 12    object
Unnamed: 13    object
Unnamed: 14    object
Unnamed: 15    object
Unnamed: 16    object
§83a           object
Unnamed: 18    object
Unnamed: 19    object
Unnamed: 20    object
Unnamed: 21    object
Unnamed: 22    object
dtype: object
```

Want to change my string in Col Total to float with this

```
dt.Total = dt.Total.astype(float)
```

Error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Total'` See below for total info

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-ad6ed6a5e004> in <module>
----> 1 dt.Total = dt.Total.astype(float)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5546         else:
   5547             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5548             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,)
   5549             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5550 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    602         self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"
    603     ) -> "BlockManager":
--> 604         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    605 
    606     def convert(

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, **kwargs)
    407                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    408             else:
--> 409                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    410             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    411 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    593             vals1d = values.ravel()
    594             try:
--> 595                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
    596             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    597                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    995     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    996         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 997         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    998 
    999     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Total'
```

UPDATED:
[image]

[image]

Comment: the first two rows of your dataframe contains string values in Total column.

Comment: Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153414/how-to-pre-process-data-before-pandas-read-csv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pandas.Series from dtype object to float, and errors to nans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952790/convert-pandas-series-from-dtype-object-to-float-and-errors-to-nans)

Comment: @HåkenLid I assume the number 0,75 can not be a number as long as it doesn't have a dot inside. So instead of 0,75 it should be 0.75 (with a "." instead of ",")

Comment: @RajatMishra I have dropped the two first column but I still have the issue. I assume it is the "," instead of "." in the decimal number

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. The string "Total" can't be parsed as a number. What number do you expect to get?

Comment: @HåkenLid: your right. I have now removed the first two lines, so the value "Total" is not a part of the col value. But I now get this error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Total'" See the updated image

Comment: Series and DataFrame are different types. There's lots of learning resources about pandas here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html

Comment: Okay, great. Lot of video materials. I will look it through :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of your columns contain a string value (even an alphabet for that matter), python will show an error while trying to convert it to ***float*** or ***int***. The first two rows of the TOTAL column are strings. For this reason, you might want to remove these or replace them with some other suitable values before attempting to convert the column values to float.