# Python zipfile writestr method. How to write large string ? (a large CSV file)

Tags: python, dynamic, python-zipfile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a zip file from a generator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297345/create-a-zip-file-from-a-generator-in-python)

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip:
     myzip.writestr('file.csv','records1,fields')
```

The above code works for creating a zip file. But I want to generate a large csv file with thousands of records. With the above code we can not append string to file 'file.csv' and I don't want to create large string in memory before writing to myzip.

Is there a way to append string to file.csv dynamically?