python requests: multipart/form-data and a generator
I used a generator as an argument to data for Content-Type application/json, and that worked fine.
The problem now is that I need to do this for multipart/form-data, and it appears to not support a generator.

I tried files={'content': my_generator_func()} and got: "a bytes-like object is required, not 'generator'"; so it looks like it would have accepted a file descriptor, but not a generator.

I then tried a generator for the data argument, and set the files argument to a form name and value: files={'encoding': (None, 'base64')} [I read you have to use the files argument to get requests to do multipart/form-data] For that I get the error "Streamed bodies and files are mutually exclusive".

Just in case, I tried it different ways setting a header for Content-Type multipart/form-data, both with and without it [I had read that setting it yourself can mess up requests.] If I omitted it, it complained it was missing; and if I included it, I got the errors previously specified.

The MultipartEncoder helper, while it does accept a file descriptor, does not accept a generator.


Is it possible to furnish a generator for multipart/form-data? If I have to, I will dump the stream into a file and pass a descriptor to the files argument; but seems that you would have furnished a way to use a generator since it is supported for Content-Type application/json
PS The closest StackOverflow post on this topic is: How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?
PPS I also tried this:
https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html#streaming-data-from-a-generator
and the endpoint is not seeing the form data being sent. [I confirmed it works with curl using --form name=value arguments.]
I was asked for a code example:
def my_generator():
    'when iterated over, this will return "value_fragment1;value_fragment2;"'
    yield 'value_fragment1;'
    yield 'value_fragment2;'

response=requests.post(url,
# tried with+without this header...
headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
data={'field1': (None, 'value1'),
      'field2': (None, 'value2')
     }, # the data argument is done the way the Stack post suggests for multipart...
files={'field3', my_generator()}
                       )
# this code generates the generator not expected error...

And using the Streaming iterator:
from requests_toolbelt.streaming_iterator import StreamingIterator
# .
# .
# .
# this is done just to get a length
# for the content in this example;
# in a real implementation we would calculate this...
content=''
for fragment in my_generator():
    content+=fragment

streamer=StreamingIterator(len(content), my_generator())
response=requests.post(url,
# tried with+without this header...
headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
data={'field1': (None, 'value1'),
      'field2': (None, 'value2')
     }, # the data argument is done the way the Stack post suggests for multipart...
files={'field3', streamer}
                       )
# the endpoint does not see the fields,
# while it sees them for a curl --form field1=value1 --form field2=value2 ...

=======================================
Tried this and plugged it into the MultipartEncoder:
How do I read a tarfile from a generator?
It is not as simple as that post thinks; you need to implement seeking functions in your BufferedReader/RawIOBase class:
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 573, in len
return total_len(self.fd) - self.fd.tell()
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek

I also tried passing a StreamingIterator to a MultipartEncoder class (where you would pass a file descriptor...), but it hangs on the request.
Looks like implementation of a generator for multipart/form-data was an oversight by the requests [toolbelt] developers...

Please provide a [mre] of your attempts so far.

I might be able to make a BufferedReader and pass it to the MultipartEncoder in place of a file descriptor.
[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155958/how-do-i-read-a-tarfile-from-a-generator/51546783#51546783#51546783 ]
