# How can i create a zip file if i have a byte array or Stream of file content in python?

Tags: python, arrays, api, stream, ironpython

I am calling a third party api which gives me a byte array or stream of zip file content as response. Now, I want create a zip file using this byte info or stream in iron python. How can i achieve the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Try TCP reassembly](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Reassembly) assuming contents are not encrypted

Comment: Do the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297345/create-a-zip-file-from-a-generator-in-python/2734156#2734156