# Create a zip file on S3 from CSV files on S3 using Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, zip

Around 60 CSV files being generated daily in my S3 bucket. The average size of each file is around 500MB. I want to zip all these files through lambda function on the fly(without downloading a file inside Lambda execution) and upload these zipped files to another s3 bucket. I came across these solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297345/create-a-zip-file-from-a-generator-in-python/55169752#55169752) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624900/how-can-i-use-boto-to-stream-a-file-out-of-amazon-s3-to-rackspace-cloudfiles) but I am still getting issue in the implementation. Right now, I am trying to stream CSV file data into a zipped file(this zip file is being created in Lambda tmp directory) and then uploading on s3. But I am getting this error message while writing into zip file:
`[Errno 36] File name too long`

This is my test Lambda function where I am just trying with one file but in actual case I need to zip 50-60 CSV files individually:

```
import boto3
import zipfile


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    iterator = s3.Object('bucket-name', 'file-name').get()['Body'].iter_lines()
    my_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/test.zip', 'w')
    for line in iterator:
        my_zip.write(line)
    
    s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(file-name, "another-bucket-name", "object-name")
```

Also, is there a way where I can stream data from my CSV file, zip it and upload it to another s3 bucket without actually saving a full zip file on Lambda memory?

Comment: What kind of data is it? If they are CSVs or other data formats Athena can read I've used a scheduled Athena-Query to zip files, but solution is a little weird ;-)

Comment: @Maurice Data is in CSV format..What was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of research and trials, I am able to make it work. I used [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) library for my issue and managed to zip 550MB file with just 150MB memory usage in my Lambda. To use external library, I had to use [Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) in Lambda. Here is my code:

```
from smart_open import open, register_compressor
import lzma, os


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    with open('s3://bucket-name-where-large-file/file-key-name') as fin:
        with open('s3://bucket-name-to-put-zip-file/zip-file-key-name', 'w') as fout:
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line)
```

Please note, smart_open supports `.gz` and `.bz2` file compression. If you want to zip file in other formats, you can create your own compressor using `register_compressor` method of this library.